# i get error in creating trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I create a table

`create table employe(Eid int,Ename varchar(20),City varchar(20),Designation varchar(20),
Salary int,perks int)`

i want to create a trigger for it but i got error

```
create trigger ins_trig before insert on employe
for each row
begin
update employe set salary=salary-300 where parks>2000;
end;
```

The error is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ins_trig, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'before'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't know any "BEFORE INSERT" triggers - only AFTER (operation) or INSTEAD OF (operation) triggers...

Comment: The inclusion of 'BERFORE' and 'FOR EACH ROW' in your trigger syntax implies you are not using SQL Server (Oracle? Informix?) but the error message looks like a SQL Server error. Please clarify which server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
create trigger ins_trig on employe before insert
```

Have a look at [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: Your trigger statement is not valid T-SQL; there is no "before insert" in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered reading the manual?: [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not SQL Server code despite a SQL Server error message.

Don't know if this works because there is no "for each row" in T-SQL either

Something like:

```
create trigger ins_trig on employe INSTEAD OF insert
AS
begin
update employe set salary=salary-300 where parks>2000;
end;
```

Looking at your code:

- have you heard of the Halloween problem?
- is it parks or perks?
- primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, you probably want this:

```
create trigger ins_trig ON employe FOR insert 
begin 
update employe set salary=salary-300 where parks>2000
end;
```